# React js: simple Web app with authentication

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to play with react to build simple Web app, but there is so many frameworks, libs etc. that I don't know even what should I search in Google.

My goal is quite simple. I need app where user can log in, and then manage the few lists of resources (CRUD operations). I have backend with API.
Login strategy which I need is only email + password - without social.

**What frameworks, tools, libraries etc. I can use to achieve my goal? (Including components which can be useful to setup project)**

Comment: Well the only thing where I see using a module would be useful is for authentication. redux-auth is a popular one. as for a simple CRUD list of resources, you really don't need a library for that. I'm sure there are some but if you're learning React and Redux it's good not to use modules and libraries for simple stuff otherwise you won't learn the basics. If you want, Jumpsuit is a cool wrapper for React and Redux, makes the state management part of Redux a little bit cleaner and feels more concise (to me, anyway. Just google 'jumpsuit github')

Comment: Oh and Jumpsuit also has build tools built into it so you don't need to set them up either, another useful thing :)

Comment: Have a look at this repo for a react app with basic authentication https://github.com/StephenGrider/AdvancedReduxCode